# String Array Keeps Printing Last Entry in C

Tags: c

I don't quite understand why when I run the code, inputting with 5 different strings, it prints string[0] as the last string that I enter:

for example, if I input:

yes
no
it would print:

Check yes

yes

yes

Check no

no

no

even for index=0

```
int main(void) {
   char *string[5];
   char entered[11];
   for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
     scanf("%s", &entered);
     string[j] = entered;
     printf("Check %s\n",entered);    
     printf("%s\n",string[j]); 
     printf("%s\n",string[0]); 
       }
   return 0;
 }
```

My intention is to save each string entry into the array.

So for my example, I want:

Check yes

yes

yes

Check no

no

yes

I am not allowed to use malloc...etc.

Comment: Increase the warning level of your compiler, and **mind the warnings**.

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
     string[j] = entered;
```

does not copy characters from `entered` to `string[j]`; rather, it sets `string[j]` to point to the memory location of the `entered` array.

You need to allocate memory for the strings in your `string` array, by writing (e.g.):

```
char string[5][11];
```

instead of

```
char *string[5];
```

and then you need to copy characters from `entered` from `string[j]` by writing (e.g.):

```
     strcmp(string[j], entered);
```